# How Can I Connect Visual Studio 2008 to Team Foundation Service and Visual Studio Online?

Tags: visual-studio-2008, tfs, azure-devops, visual-studio-2008-sp1

I've made sure that I have all of the prerequisites covered, then tried to install the patch from here:

- [Visual Studio 2008 SP1 Compatibility GDR for Visual Studio 2012 Team Foundation Server and Team Foundation Service Preview](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=29983)

When I do so, I end up with this message:

[image]

OK - so, believing that perhaps I have already installed software which covers the update I try to add my TFS preview server to Visual Studio 2008 Team Explorer (with settings that match what I have in VS 2012):

[image]

This tries to connect for maybe 30 - 60 seconds and then quits with this error message:

[image]

What am I doing wrong? From reading other blog posts it appears that Team Foundation Service is supported in both VS 2010 and VS 2008.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

Visual Studio 2010 introduced the concept of a Project Collection, so the hierarchy looks like:

```
Server - Project Collection A - Project A
                              - Project B
       - Project Collection B - Project C
                              - Project D
                              - Project E
```

In TFS 2005 and 2008 the Project Collection didn't exist, so the hierarchy looked like this:

```
Server - Project A
       - Project B
       - Project C
```

Due to this change you need to point Visual Studio 2008 and 2005 to a project collection and not to the server. They think each ProjectCollection is its own server.

So, when connecting from an old version of Visual Studio to a 2010 or newer version of TFS, you need to use the projectcollection uri in the connect to server window, something along these lines:

> `https://yourtfsname.visualstudio.com/DefaultCollection/`
>   `http://yourtfsname.yourdomain.com:8080/tfs/DefaultCollection/`

In order for Visual Studio 2005 or 2008 to connect, you also need to ensure that the proper forward compatibility patches are installed. [This blog post covers all versions of Visual Studio and Team Foundation server and lists exactly which patches you need to install and in which order to install them](http://blog.jessehouwing.nl/2013/10/connecting-to-tfs-from-any-version-of.html) (order is important!).

The version of Visual Studio, TFS and Windows influence the exact set of files to install, they're all listed in the blogpost mentioned.

Comment: Thanks for this. I read your blog post and am in fact getting the error about not using slashes (`/`). This is odd, since I can't install the patch which is supposed to fix that. And I've already covered the prerequisites at the start of your article. Any other ideas?

Comment: Did you install vs2008sp1 first?

Comment: I reapplied all of the updates in the order of your blog post and I'm now able to connect to TFS. Thank you!

Comment: nice one, been trying to figure this out. It'd be nice if the docs mentioned it :)

Comment: anyone having problems with VS2008 putting the port number at the end of the url instead of after the server as in the example? How do I prevent that?

Comment: @drzounds try manually specifying the full url, instead of using the individual textboxes.

Comment: Thanks, that's saved my hours.